# Regex - capture text between matches, and if no match, capture all

Tags: r, regex

I'm quite new at regex, and I'm trying to capture text between two strings. But if the strings don't exist, I would like to capture all text.

Here is an example:

> Report #1: Observations: A cat is stretching. Conclusions: This cat is flexible.

And I can use the following code to capture the text between "Observations" and "*Conclusions*":

```
(?:(?i)observations)(.*)(?:(?i)conclusions)
```

But if another text writes:

> Report #1: Observations: A cat is stretching. This cat is flexible.

I'd like to capture everything after "*Observations*".

Or if the starting string "*Observations*" doesn't exist:

> Report #1: A cat is stretching. Conclusions: This cat is flexible.

I'd  like to capture from the start to the ending string "*Conclusions*".

I guess conditional regex may help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you working in R?

Comment: You might try https://regex101.com/r/RdMnFA/1

Comment: @WiktorStribizew Yes I am. Wow thank you! it looks neat. I guess it has to be this long for the conditional to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
ex <- c(
  "Report #1: Observations: A cat is stretching. Conclusions: This cat is flexible.",
  "Report #1: Observations: A cat is stretching. This cat is flexible.",
  "Report #1: A cat is stretching. Conclusions: This cat is flexible."
)

gsub("(^.*observations|conclusions.*$)", "", ex, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] ": A cat is stretching. "                     
# [2] ": A cat is stretching. This cat is flexible."
# [3] "Report #1: A cat is stretching. "
```

You might want boundaries or as G5W suggested spaces before/after the words. Word boundaries would look like this, with the same output given the sample text:

```
gsub("(^.*\\bobservations\\b|\\bconclusions\\b.*$)", "", ex, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is with two regular expressions:

```
reports = c(
"Report #1: Observations: A cat is stretching. Conclusions: This cat is flexible.", 
"Report #1: Observations: A cat is stretching. This cat is flexible.")

reports = sub(".*Observations:\\s*", "", reports)
reports = sub("\\s*Conclusions:.*", "", reports)

reports
[1] "A cat is stretching."                      
[2] "A cat is stretching. This cat is flexible."
```

Comment: Any reason for the expectation of white space? I don't think that was a requirement.

Comment: There is whitespace in the example data.

Comment: Yes but not in the requirement for parsing. I don't think it's contextually incorrect, but the OP did not reference spaces. I think perhaps a better expectation would be boundary `\\b`.

Comment: My interpretation of the desired output.  I admit that it is not literally "everything after Observations:"